# Не выдается питание от USB OTG отладочных плат Discovery и nucleo

Tags: usb, stm32

Есть две платы: stm32f407 Discovery и stm32f767 Nucleo. У обоих есть 2 разъёма: 1 для прошивки через ST Link, второй USB OTG, для работы МК в качестве USB устройства. Проблема вот в чём, платы не берут питание непосредственно с USB OTG при подключении через провод к компу и, соответственно, не включаются. Для включения приходиться заводить питание другим способом. Всю инициализацию провожу в CubeMX. Дык вопрос вот в чём: у меня обе платы сломаные, я неправильно инициализацию в cubemx выполнил, если да, то на что надо обратить внимание, или же это норма, что питание нужно ещё каким-то "макаром" заводить?

Answer (score 1):

Это особенность данных устройств. Они должны брать питание только от основного USB-разъёма, через который они прошиваются. Если объединить цепи питания этих двух USB-разъёмов, может возникнуть ошибка на хосте.

Вот фрагмент принципиальной схемы платы stm32f407 Discovery. Вот основной разъём USB программатора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разъём USB OTG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, их цепи питания не совмещены. Это сделано потому, что нет OTG предполагает функционирование платы как в режиме USB Device, где оно получает питание от внешнего устройства, так и USB Host， в котором сама плата Discovery должна выдавать напряжение для подключения устройств USB.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Тогда есть ещё вопрос, можно ли распотрошить USB кабель и завести +5 В и GND на плату, а +D и -D в разъём usb otg, чтобы запускать с одного провода?

Comment: @Nowsan, если при этом не будет подключаться программатор, то можно. Только лучше нн потрошить кабель, а бросить перемычку между 5в разъема программатора и 5в разъема  OTG.